# Display WooCommerce tab based on product attribute value

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the code below to add a tab to display additional product data when available in an external database. It works great, however, I only want the tab to display when the attribute "pa_data-quality" equals "icecat" (to avoid having a blank tab when data is not available). I can't seem to get it to work with if statements, and can't seem to find anything in WC documentation.

````
function woo_new_product_tab( $tabs ) {

$tabs['featurestab'] = array(
    'title'     => __( 'From the Manufacturer', 'woocommerce' ),
    'priority'  => 0,
    'callback'  => 'icecat_tab_content');
    unset( $tabs['description'] );          // Remove the description tab
    return $tabs;
}

function icecat_tab_content() {
  echo '<div id="Container3"></div>
        <div id="Container4"></div>
        <div id="Container5"></div>
        <div id="Container6"></div>
        <div id="Container7"></div>
        <div id="Container9"></div>
        <div id="Container10"></div>
        <div id="Container11"></div>';
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_new_product_tab' );```
````

Answer (score 0):

We used a workaround using tags instead of the attribute value. Works perfectly.

```html
/* adds tab for icecat product data */
function woo_new_product_tab( $tabs ) {
  
    global $product;
 
    if ( has_term( 'icecat', 'product_tag' ) ) {

$tabs['featurestab'] = array(
    'title'     => __( 'From the Manufacturer', 'woocommerce' ),
    'priority'  => 0,
    'callback'  => 'icecat_tab_content');
    unset( $tabs['description'] );          // Remove the description tab
    return $tabs;
}
}

function icecat_tab_content() {
  echo '<div id="Container3"></div>
        <div id="Container4"></div>
        <div id="Container5"></div>
        <div id="Container6"></div>
        <div id="Container7"></div>
        <div id="Container9"></div>
        <div id="Container10"></div>
        <div id="Container11"></div>';
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_new_product_tab' );
```